# Sending clicks to webpage while user is logged out via python

Tags: python, windows, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I currently have multiple scripts that rely on selenium chrome driver to navigate webpages, clicking radio boxes, drop down menus etc to apply filters to data before grabbing the file it produces.  I work in an environment where our servers log off users every 15 minutes of inactivity (easy enough to get around with a simple clicking script) and every 24 hours even if you are active (here is the issue) so I cannot use selenium chrome driver forever.  Eventually I will go on a vacation, and without me logged into the box, chromedriver fails to launch.

I need a way to click radio boxes, hover and click on drop down menus, and type into web forms with python, but without selenium.  I cannot find any documentation on requests having these features but I am hopeful that our community will come through for me

Comment: If _...without selenium..._ why tagging Selenium?

Comment: @DebanjanB im looking for similarities, or modifications to the usage of selenium. People following selenium may be aware of this limitation and know work arounds because they have also faced this issue

Comment: check if there is any API call that suites your requirement and use `requests` module in python. I am sure this will work for running the tests. and if you want to kick off the script when the server is back after 24 hours you can include it in the start-up or scheduler.